# Export content from ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell-2.0, active-directory-group

I am attempting to create a PowerShell command that finds and exports the owner of each distribution list provided in a CVS.

```
[PS] C:\WINDOWS\system32>Import-Csv $path_import | ForEach-Object {Get-QADGroup $_.Identity | select ManagedBy,Name | Export-Csv $path_export}
```

Currently the script will output to the screen the information I am trying to capture but only export the last line.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Import-Csv $path_import | ForEach-Object {Get-QADGroup $_.Identity | 
select ManagedBy,Name } | Export-Csv $path_export -notypeinformation
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you, i'd been fiddling with that for the past half hour.